# How to pass data from child component to parent [Angular]

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular. I want to see how a Child component `Output` data to Parent component. I've gone through some articles and documentation then created a minimal program. I'm able to send data from Parent to Child successfully but not the vice-versa. I'm not getting any error but I'm not getting the values also. Can you please see my code and correct me. Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odc4sq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working, you just don't show the value of ChildCurrentVal anywhere.

Put

```
{{ChildCurrentVal}}
```

In the template somewhere

Answer (score 1):

working demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvuuot)

You have missed to place `{{ChildCurrentVal}}` in `app.component.html` and not only that your child component will return value only when your child receive value from parent otherwise it return `undefined`.

Comment: Yes Himanshu, I realized that. Such a silly mistake. I'm new to Angular and web development.

Comment: @Tanzeel No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksdqyr

Comment: Your parent.component.html `<child (outputToParent)="GetOutputVal($event)"></child>` should have this. And your child.component.html is missing **ngModel** and **ngModelChange** like this: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="sendToParent($event)">`